# Create a new table based on conditional statements and multiple emails

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, vlookup

Hi InnerCircle members,

I have a table(i) like this:

[image]

I want to create a new table, which shows what kind of cert a person passed:

[image]

I tried to use Excel functions:

[image]

VLOOKUP returns the 1st result it searches. I got the wrong results. For instance, it returns No in AWS for test325@gmail.com, because CompTIA is the 1st value.

Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks for your time and your help.

Comment: You need to use `FILTER()` Function here since there are multiple instances for one email id. What is your Excel Version?

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya - My excel version is 2021.

Comment: Ok, so the second image is the expected output right!

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya - That's correct. The 2nd image is the right and expected output I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this way, using `FILTER()` Function,

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

• Formula used in cell **D1**

```
=UNIQUE(A2:A5)
```

• Formula used in cell **E1**

```
=IF(FILTER($B$2:$B$5,($D2=$A$2:$A$5)*(E$1=$B$2:$B$5),"")=E$1,"Yes","No")
```

And Fill Down & Drag Right!

You can also use the `COUNTIFS()` Function as well for **Yes** & **No**,

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$5,$D2,$B$2:$B$5,E$1)>0,"Yes","No")
```

Comment: It works perfectly in excel! Thanks. But, I'm curious whether or not this method can be used in Google spreadsheet?

Comment: I am not sure about it though, this is because though `Excel` & `GS` looks alike but functionality differs a lot, although these functions are available in `GS` as well, let me try and confirm with you!

Comment: @Kate in google sheet the second formula will be like this `=IF(IFNA(FILTER($B$2:$B$5,($D2=$A$2:$A$5)*(E$1=$B$2:$B$5)),"")=E$1,"Yes","No")`

Comment: @Kate have you tried the `GS` formula,

Comment: It worked (woohoo!!) Thanks for helping me and I truly learned a lot!

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please accept the same as an answer/upvote